# laravel breeze doesn't work in production?

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

I made my first laravel project using Breeze authentification (laravel 9.2).
Everything is ok in local, I can register and login users.
But unfortunately in production on my server, login form and register form don't work so well !

I made a second laravel project, with only authentification functionnality to check if the problem come from part of my app.   But the problem repeats : nice in local, does'nt work in production... I don't understand why.

When I submit my new created user or login with an existing user, the form reloads without performing the action...
I have this 404 error in my network console :

```
POST    https://www.prod-breeze.yannpollet.fr/register     [HTTP/2 404 Not Found 411ms]
```

My route login or register exists of course, created automatically with breeze installation.

I read in some forum that Breeze doesn't support https, but i can't believe it.

Anyone has the same problem or know hot to resolve it ?

Comment: Not supporting https???  No, don't believe it.  Of COURSE it works with https.
Did you remember to copy .htaccess file?  What webserver is it?

Comment: of course it works with https :) Well, I don't know how or why but yesterday, after 1 day of unecessary efforts trying to make it work, I just tried again a new installation and that worked. No reason... Maybe a temporal problem on my host server, I don't know.